# Can't retrieve href url attribute

Tags: puppeteer

I can't return the href, i did check all pages of stackoverflow to see if there is an solution, but sadly i did try a lot of them and non work.

This is how it looks:

```
<a href="https://test.cc/l/2342942">this is a test</a>
```

when i want to copy the selector it shows me this:

```
#bodyblock > ul > li:nth-child(1) > h4 > a
```

Well when i use that selector it shows me only the text (this is a test) not the link..
i need the url of that link.

i did try something like this,

```
var titlesList = document.querySelectorAll('#bodyblock > ul > li:nth-child(1) ');
```

or this

```
var titlesList = document.querySelectorAll('#bodyblock > ul > li:nth-child(1) ').href;
```

and this

```
let list = await page.$$eval('#bodyblock > ul > li:nth-child(1) > h4 ', a => a.href);
    console.log (list)
```

none returns the url, what am i doing wrong?.

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the selector that gets you the `a` element, then get the `href` off of that. Guessing from the selectors you have posted above, one possible way to do that:

```
const url = await page.$eval('#bodyblock > ul > li:nth-child(1) > h4 > a', el => el.href);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    function getHref(){
       var attrHref = document.querySelector("a").getAttribute("href");
       console.log(attrHref);
    }
    getHref();
```

`.getAttribute("href")` should return the url.

Find a fiddle of the above code here:
https://jsbin.com/lototozezu/edit?html,js,console,output